# Filtering blog posts by category

Tags: categories

I'm pretty new to theme development, and trying to put together a new theme.

On my site, I'd like to set up some categories for the various blog posts. Easy enough. Then, I'd like to provide the user with a menu option that would take them to a page showing all posts that match only that specific category.

I have this working after making some tweaks to the index.php file, which is acting as my blog index - but I'd like to keep this as it is, and then have separate pages that filter the index of posts by category. So there might be a "Movies" index page, and a "Directors" index page.

I tried creating a new Page which had a template that would check the post categories .. but I think the bit I'm missing, is how to get a list of all actual blog posts from within a "Page".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with a bit more digging, it seems there are two things I can do:

1. Use the Categories menu option, which will then make use of the archive.php template - nice and easy.
2. Use the WP_Query() function to make a direct DB query for a particular category .. I think this is exactly what I want to do.